# Starting Node.js using forever with --nouse-idle-notification and other flags

Tags: node.js

Previously, I started my production node app via:

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

However, per the suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887062/node-v8-garbage-collector-how-to-debug-long-mark-sweep-times/12895144#12895144), I'd like to start node with --nouse-idle-notification. I also found [this article](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/) about setting --max-old-space-size, etc. Unfortunately, nobody I ask can seem to figure out how to tell if the flag is actually accepted by node, so I'm not sure how to tell if my forever syntax is correct.

Furthermore, I can't get forever to accept both arguments...

Eg, if I use this

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start --max-old-space-size=8192 --nouse-idle-notification index.js
```

I get the "forever usage information", as if I had tried to start forever without passing a .js file to run (eg, just typing "forever"). If I put the flags before the "start" command, it seems to start, but again I'm not sure how to tell if the flags were accepted...

Can someone please help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 15):

You need to pass -c parameter:

```
forever start -c "node --max-old-space-size=8192 --nouse-idle-notification" index.js
```

If you list the processes, you'll see the flags are honoured.

```
forever list
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really love forever for some other reason, try [mon](https://github.com/visionmedia/mon).

It's super easy to pass flags because you can specify the exact command:

```
mon "node --max-old-space-size=8192 --nouse-idle-notification --expose-gc server.js" -d
```

It monitors only a node process. If you want to monitor a group of processes like forever does, install [mongroup](https://github.com/jgallen23/mongroup), its a bash script that manages `mon`.

This will save you some RAM, specially if you're monitoring a lot of node processes (I think forever launches one additional node process for every process you want to monitor).

quick tip: last time I checked, TJ Holowaychuk's branch of `mon` was not working well under linux (I guess he only tested on Mac), but [this one](https://github.com/jgallen23/mon) works and its the one I'm using right now. **EDIT**: Actually 2 days ago [the issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/mon/pull/3) was closed and the main branch should now be working.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
forever start --max-old-space-size=8192 --nouse-idle-notification -c "NODE_ENV=production node" index.js
```

Comment: Well, that certainly started the server successfully... but I have no way of knowing if the flags are being interpreted by node correctly :(

Comment: Btw, I had to do it this way: NODE_ENV=production forever start --max-old-space-size=8192 --nouse-idle-notification -c "node" index.js

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure the "binary" forever will pass the env to node. To know for sure just output the env `console.log(process.env)`

Comment: Good call; that worked. Still no idea how to check if the --max-old-space-size and --nouse-idle-notification flags are getting passed though :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I've confirmed that this is not passing the flags through to node. I added the --expose-gc flag which makes me able to use the gc() function when I start node with this flag, but the gc() function is undefined when I use this forever technique.